# Change icon position in swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, nsattributedstring

I have the following code which shows an icon on the left side of a uilabel, my question is how can I put the icon on the right side of the uilabel:

```
let attachment = NSTextAttachment()
attachment.image = UIImage(named: "ic_person")
attachment.bounds = CGRect(x: 0, y: -3, width: 15, height: 15)
let attachmentStr = NSAttributedString(attachment: attachment)
let myString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "")
myString.append(attachmentStr)
let myString1 = NSMutableAttributedString(string: item_empresa[indexPath.item].nombre_emp!)
myString.append(myString1)
cell.lbl_nombreEmpresa.attributedText = myString
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put the image after the text by appending attachment after appending the text itself

```
let attachment = NSTextAttachment()
attachment.image = UIImage(named: "ic_person")
attachment.bounds = CGRect(x: 0, y: -3, width: 15, height: 15)

let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: item_empresa[indexPath.item].nombre_emp ?? "")

attributedString.append(NSAttributedString(attachment: attachment))
cell.lbl_nombreEmpresa.attributedText = attributedString
```

Comment: my friend how can I change the color of my image?

Comment: @DiegoIsraelMoreno I created this UIImage extension for you on [github](https://github.com/omiz/UIImage-Color/blob/master/UIImage.swift) just add the file and use it like this `image.with(color: .white)`

Comment: I have this warning result of call to 'with(color:) ' is unused

Comment: Did you add the file from GitHub first

Comment: Yes with the name UIImage.swift

Comment: after that I do this 
let image:UIImage=UIImage(named:"ic_premium")!
            image.with(color: UIColor.green)
            let attachment = NSTextAttachment() .......

Comment: Yeah :D :D it works :D can you go to my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47587180/set-tint-color-to-image-in-swift-3?noredirect=1#comment82131891_47587180 to give you a correct answer

Comment: the question is closed